# Why is `ls -lF` listing files with the prefix "~$" not present in the directory?

Tags: bash, shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm currently practicing basic Shell Commands in WSL, Windows Subsystem for Linux (I do not have a linux system but I want to get familiar with commands).

I start a bash session on the command prompt window and navigate to my desktop using `cd` . In desktop I noticed that after using `ls -lF` some files with the prefix ~$ appear, such as: `'~$executable.x'*` or `'~$file.txt'`
These files are not currently present under the desktop directory, but I was able to remember that they were at one point (varying from a week to months ago). 
When I do the same process in powershell windows (not using linux commands) I noticed that files displayed match the desktop and no extra files are listed.

I was wondering if **anyone could explain what ~$ means in this context?** my intuition is telling me they are backed up files that are somehow hidden in the desktop. After googling, all I could find is that ~ reefers to the home. I also understand that $ is the default prompt symbol for the bash shell when it is waiting for me to type something, but I'm still confused on why it would show up as a prefix for the name of a file.

Hope I made my question clear.
I'm currently reading "Linux® Command Line and Shell Scripting BIBLE" by Blum and Bresnahan but I could not find an answer there, this is my last resource after many googling attempts. Any other source for more information on the topic would be helpful.

Comment: If the files had been there in the past, but are not here anymore, and you don't even know that this are files you need, why care about it? If they appear again, keep the output of `ls -lF` so we can at least get some information on the files (such as size or owner). From the odd name, my guess would be that these are temporary files created by some application.

Comment: They're Word backups. See https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000527.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, files that start with `~` are used for hidden files. More specifically,, the prefix `~$` are often used as backups for programs, should they crash before writing updates to a file (e.g. Microsoft Word, etc.)

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde):

> The tilde symbol is used to prefix hidden temporary files that are created when a document is opened in Windows. For example, when you open a Word document called “Document1.doc,” a file called “~$cument1.doc” is created in the same directory. This file contains information about which user has the file open, to prevent multiple users from attempting to change a document at the same time.

See: [Why does Word make temporary files?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/211632/description-of-how-word-creates-temporary-files)

Relevant superuser question: https://superuser.com/questions/405257/what-type-of-file-is-file